# PDF R Markdown não gerado

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Comecei a usar o RStudio no Windows 10 há pouco tempo. Tentei a operação básica para salvar um PDF do R Markdown, contudo, ao gerar o R Markdown, o arquivo não aparece como .rmd, mesmo tendo renomeado o arquivo. Tento salvar como PDF, mas quando aciono Knit, ele abre o diretório com a opção para salvar "all files" e não como PDF (mesmo eu já tendo selecionado a opção PDF).
Ainda que o arquivo seja salvo desse modo (all files), a janela com o PDF que deveria abrir no RStudio não aparece.

O que está ocorrendo de errado?

Já instalei os pacotes rmarkdown, tinytex e o latexpdf, mas ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Erro: LaTeX failed to compile Relatório.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
Além disso: Warning messages:
1: In has_crop_tools() : 
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: pdfcrop, ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
2: In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"pdflatex"' not found
Execução interrompida

No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/

  If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

Answer (score -2):

Cara Juliana,

Você deve instalar um compilador para LaTex.  Para o Windows 10 existem vários disponíveis.  O endereço do compilador de LaTex deve estar no path do seu ambiente de trabalho.

Comment: Prezado Alexandre, muito obrigada pela informação! Seguindo às suas orientações, consegui resolver o problema com a instalação do TexLive. Tentei com o MikTex, porém, tanto a instalação completa quanto a básica, não funcionaram no meu Windows 10.